# Unable to create dag with apache airflow

Tags: airflow

I am running `airflow 2.0`, setting up airflow dag for the first time, and following quick start tutorials.

After creating and running the `py` file I don't see the dag created it does not list for me.

setting:
`airflow.cfg:dags_folder = /Users/vik/src/airflow/dags`
my python file is in this folder. There are no errors here.

I am able to see the example dags in example-dags.

I did airflow `db` init
airflow webserver
airflow scheduler
then try to list the dags
I think I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you installed everything, but I highly recommend [Astronomer CLI](https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cloud/stable/develop/cli-quickstart) for simplicity and quick setup. With that you'll be able to setup a first DAG pretty quickly. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OihokE8u9D0) is also the video tutorial that helps you understand how to install / setup everything.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- Make sure the `scheduler`is running (run `airflow scheduler`) or try to restart it .
- Using the Airflow CLI, run `airflow config list` and make sure that the loaded config is in fact what you are expecting, check the value of `dags_folder`.
- Try running `airflow dags list` from the CLI, and check the the `filepath` if your dag is shown in the results.
- If there was an error parsing your DAG, and therefore could not be loaded by the scheduler, you can find the logs in `${AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs/scheduler/${date}/your_dag_id.log`

Comment: I found some success, I did all the above before i posted here. Seems like scheduler is not picking up the dag untill i  restart all services.   OR may be theres a latancy. Do we need to restart everyhting  everytime i add new dag?

Comment: No, that should not be necessary at all. Althought there is an interval of time since you add a new DAG and the scheduler discovers it. That is defined by the setting called ` min_file_process_interval`.

Comment: Here is the link to the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval).

Comment: Also check : [dag_dir_list_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-dir-list-interval) Which I think it's more accurate to your question. Let me know if that worked for you!